# Cannot find file: 'index.js' does not match the corresponding name on disk: '.\node_modules\Victory\es\victory'

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, victory-charts

I was trying to represent csv data using chart on react.
I have no clue about the error occurring.
I have installed d3 as well as victory.

My code

[image]

Error occurring

[image]

Comment: Looks like the you should be importing from `"victory"` (lower-cased V)

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code, errors or other text. Copy the original text here instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace

```
import { VictoryBar, VictoryChart } from "Victory";
```

By

```
import { VictoryBar, VictoryChart } from "victory";
```